# Как убрать ограничение в 500 результатов в gmailAPI для python

Tags: python, gmail

Планирую написать программу, которая считает количество отправленных и полученных сообщений в определенный день, не могу найти как в `maxResults` убрать ограничение, большие значения не помогают.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import pprint
import os.path
import pickle

from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.json.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly']


def gmail_authenticate():
    creds = None
    # the file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first time
    if os.path.exists("token.pickle"):
        with open("token.pickle", "rb") as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)
    # if there are no (valid) credentials availablle, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file('client.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # save the credentials for the next run
        with open("token.pickle", "wb") as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)
    return build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds)

# get the Gmail API service
service = gmail_authenticate()
msgs = service.users().messages().list(userId='me',maxResults=50000).execute()


for msg in msgs['messages']:
    m_id = msg['id'] # get id of individual message
    message = service.users().messages().get(userId='me', id=m_id).execute()
    payload = message['payload']
    header = payload['headers']
    #print(header[0]['name'],' '.join(header[1]['value'].split()[6:11]))
    print(header[0]['name'],header[1]['value'])
```

Comment: Никак, на то они и ограничения.

Comment: Может все-таки есть какая нибудь возможность обработать все сообщения?

Comment: Конечно есть, запросить первые 500 штук, потом следующие 500 шт, и так пока не запросите все пиьсма :) вы документацию смотрели?

Comment: А где именно в документации это написано :D

Comment: Да прям вот тут: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/list
```pageToken string       Page token to retrieve a specific page of results in the list.```

Comment: и последний вопрос, как узнать максимальное количество страниц, если это возможно?

Comment: Ну серьезно? ну гляньте вы по ссылке, в наш то век если не знаете английский - есть переводчики... 
```resultSizeEstimate integer (uint32 format)  -> Estimated total number of results.```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение получается примерно такое:

```
messages = []
next_page_token = None

for _ in range(3):# 3 здесь количество страниц
    if next_page_token:
        msgs = service.users().messages().list(userId='me',maxResults=500, pageToken=next_page_token).execute()
    else:
        msgs = service.users().messages().list(userId='me',maxResults=500).execute()

    messages.extend(msgs)
    next_page_token = msgs['nextPageToken']
```